# using exclusive ranges with regular expressions Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, range

How can i make this code into one line with a regular expression that looks for exclusive ranges?

I have used a regular expression with inclusive ranges in this:

```
word = "square"
if word.include?("qu")
    word2=word
    two = word.slice!(word[/.*qu/])
    one = word2.slice(word)
    puts one + two + "ay"
end
```

But I feel like I have not made use of either regular expressions to their potential or ruby string methods to their full potential.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`String#sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) with capturing group:

```
"square".sub(/(.*qu)(.*)/, '\2\1ay')
# => "aresquay"
```

Comment: thanks. the first part of the regex takes everything up to and including the "qu" ~ (.*qu). and the second part (.*) says everything to the end of the string? what is the \2\1ay? and what is the logic behind the brackets with the regex?

Comment: @ZachSmith, `(..)` in the regular expression create a capturing group, numbered `1`, `2` in order. `\1`, `\2`, ... in the substitute string reference that matched group.  See [`Class: REgexp : Capturing` from Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing) for more explanation.

Comment: Zach, `\1` and `\2` are the strings captured by each of the two capture groups, respectively (left-to-right). so `\1 => "squ"` and `\2 => "are"`.  The same values are placed in the global variables, `$1` and `$2`, so you don't have to take my word for it; run it in IRB and see what `$1` and `$2` are.